# Installing wifi driver

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

I have installed Debian 9 and everything looks great I'm just struggling to install my wifi adapters drivers. I have found the adapter driver [here](https://www.tp-link.com/za/download/TL-WN725N.html). I'm just very new to the console and need a bit of guidance in using it.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [installation guide](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201805/20180508/Installation%20Guide%20for%20Linux.pdf):

- Make sure your kernel is up to date: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, then reboot.
- Go to the folder where you downloaded the driver in a terminal (like `cd ~/Downloads/wifidrv/`).
- Check your compiler version with `cat /proc/version | grep "gcc version"`. The version number is after `gcc version` (which should be in red). If it is at least 5.4.0, you can continue.
- Compile the driver with `make clean` and then `make`.
- After the commands finish, you should see a `.ko` file in the directory (you can find the name with `ls | grep ".ko"`.
- Then, load the driver with the following:

  ```
  sudo cp 88x2bu.ko /lib/modules/[kernel version]/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
  # Make sure to replace (above) [kernel version] with your current kernel version.
  sudo depmod -a
  sudo modprobe 88x2bu.ko
  ```

Make sure `88x2bu.ko` is the wifi driver's name.

Then, check to see if the driver installed by running `lsmod`. If it didn't, reboot and try `lsmod` again.